# React hot reload doesn't work in docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up React with docker, but for some reason I cannot get the hot reload to work. Currently, if I create a file it recompiles, but if I change something in a file it does not. Also, I didn't change any packages or configuration files, the project was generated with `npx create-react-app projectname --template typescript`.

From researching this online I found out that I needed to add `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to a .env file, I tried this but it didn't work, I tried placing the .env in all directories in case I placed it in the wrong one. I also added it to the docker-compose.yml environment.

In addition to this, I also tried downgrading react-scripts to 4.0.3 because I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11879), that also didn't work.

I also tried changing a file locally and then checking if it also changes inside the docker container, it does, so I'm pretty sure my docker related files are correct.

**Versions**

- Node 16.14
- Docker Desktop 4.5.1 (Windows)
- react 17.0.2
- react-scripts 5.0.0

**Directory structure**

```
project/
│   README.md
│   docker-compose.yml    
│
└───frontend/
    │   Dockerfile
    │   package.json
    │   src/
    │   ...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "./frontend:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Dockerfile you have is great for when you want to package your app into a container, ready for deployment. It's not so good for development where you want to have the source outside the container and have the running container react to changes in the source.

What I do is keep the Dockerfile for packaging the app and only build that, when I'm done.

When developing, I can often do that without a dockerfile at all, just by running a container and mapping my source code into it.

For instance, here's a command I use to run a node app

```
docker run -u=1000:1000 -v $(pwd):/app -w=/app -d -p 3000:3000 --rm --name=nodedev node bash -c "npm install && npm run dev"
```

As you can see, it just runs a standard node image. Let me go through the different parts of the command:

`-u 1000:1000` 1000 is my UID and GID on the host. By running the container using the same ids, any files created by the container will be owned by me on the host.

`-v $(pwd):/app` map the current directory into the /app directory in the container

`-w /app` set the working directory in the container to /app

`-d` run detached

`-p 3000:3000` map port 3000 in the container to 3000 on the host

`--rm` remove the container when it exits

`-name=nodedev` give it a name, so    I can kill it without looking up the name

at the end there's a command for the container `bash -c "npm install && npm run dev"` which starts by installing any dependencies and then runs the dev script in the package.json file. That script starts up node in a mode, where it hot reloads.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I had to adapt it a little to run on Windows, I removed ```-u 1000:1000``` and changed ```$(pwd)``` into ```${pwd}```. The files are synced between the container and my local files, and they update when I change something, but react still doesn't recompile when I change something.

Comment: Recompiling is something your script in package.json needs to make sure happens. You run the "start" script which probably doesn't do hot reload.

Comment: But when I run ```npm run start``` locally, it does hot reload.

Comment: You might have to add `-e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to the command on Windows, since there's an issue where file update notifications aren't sent to Linux containers when you use WSL.

Comment: Just tried that as well and it still doesn't work when I edit a file, only when I create one. I've also tried it on a new React project but that doesn't work either. I have no clue why it isn't working.

Comment: That's strange. I tried it on Ubuntu with npx create-react-app and it works as it should with this command `docker run -u=1000:1000 -v $(pwd):/app -w=/app -d -p 3000:3000 --rm --name=nodedev node bash -c "npm install && npm start"`. It must be something WSL related.

Comment: Yep I think you're right, I found [this WSL2 issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739), and I can't find any workaround either. I'll just run it without a container during development. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @bortgerres One last shot. Can you try using this command from a Windows command line in the directory with your code? It has to be the command line for %cd% to work. `docker run -v %cd%:/app -w=/app -d -p 3000:3000 -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true --rm --name=nodedev node bash -c "npm install && npm start"`

Answer (score 37):

If you are on Windows and use react-scripts 5.x.x or above, CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING is not working. Make changes your package.json instead in the following way:

```
    "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "WATCHPACK_POLLING=true react-scripts start",
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent a long time to overcome this problem , as the CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING did not work at all (windows 10 v19044, react-app 18.0 with node 18)

However, I experienced  a huge delay after each change. I know it is not perfect and polling is absolutely resource consuming, but is there any solution for faster response ?

Comment: I've also experienced some delay, but it's not so critical to bother about. As a rough idea, I may suggest to experiment with watchpack settings to exclude node-modules and set proper timeouts. Also, the cause of slow-down may be in docker container, so you may check it by changing its settings.

Comment: added "WATCHPACK_POLLING=true" as environment in my nodejs-instance in docker-compose, hot reload works for me, now I don't even have to reload the website, content refreshing automaticle after edit and saving file. thanks!

Comment: `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` stopped working for me after switching from WSL1 to WSL2. Using`WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` instead fixed that.

Answer (score 7):

Polling wasn't my issue -- watching the docker output I saw it recompiled correctly.  My problem was related to networking in the hot loader.  I found that the browser is trying to open a websocket back to the node server to `ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node` but whatever network settings are like on my computer, this wouldn't route back to the docker container.  I added

```
WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

to the environment variables.  After restarting, the browser successfully connects to `ws://127.0.0.1:3000/sockjs-node` and hot reloading works properly.

This was tied to using a docker-compose solution similar to the original post.  I was able to also make things with with a variation on the docker run approach, but it was much slower to launch.

Answer (score 5):

Consuming all sayed above I got worked version for Docker.

So if you are used Docker compose file, just edit to your `docker-compose.yml` and add some enviroment:

```
services:
  frontend: 
    environment:
      - WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1 
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true 
    command: npm run start
```

OR

into `packages.json`:

`WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1  CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true WATCHPACK_POLLING=true react-scripts start`

But this will be work only localy for development server. Into remote server this can't be works.

Answer (score 1):

WSL Workaround for CRA 5.0+

*watch.js*

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const webPackConfigFile = path.resolve('./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');
  let webPackConfigFileText = fs.readFileSync(webPackConfigFile, 'utf8');

  if (!webPackConfigFileText.includes('watchOptions')) {
    if (webPackConfigFileText.includes('performance: false,')) {
      webPackConfigFileText = webPackConfigFileText.replace(
        'performance: false,',
        "performance: false,\n\t\twatchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 200, poll: 1000, ignored: '**/node_modules', },"
      );
      fs.writeFileSync(webPackConfigFile, webPackConfigFileText, 'utf8');
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Failed to inject watchOptions`);
    }
  }
}
```

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./watch && react-scripts start",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue once, This issue was in my Dockerfile The workdir was /var/app/ while in my docker-compose.yml I mounted current working directory to /var/app/frontend, I just removed that /frontend and works fine. please check yours. thanks

Comment: Where should I remove /frontend? The volume I made is './frontend:/app'. If I remove it there it also adds the other projects like the backend into the volume I think.

Comment: the point is paths were mis-matched

Comment: Ah okay, I'm pretty sure that the docker mounts are correct though because when I create a new file in src it does recompile, but when I edit a file it does not.

Comment: Play with the paths, i am sure it is because of mis-match in paths. AndPlease do accept the answer and vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use --legacy-watch tag in package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "history",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/index.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./src/index.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and my mistake was that I was editing on my local machine and was expecting code reload inside the docker container. Since 2 of them are at different locations - it will never work out and I had to restart the docker-compose again and again.

**Later I used the vscode command palette**

> "Attach to Running Container..."

option and the selected required container and cd into my code folder and made changes and live reload (or apply code changes on the refresh page) started working.

This helped me solve one issue, the next issue is to use the local ssh-key inside the docker container such that I can do my git sync inside the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `NODE_ENV="development"` in the Dockerfile enables the hot reload

Answer (score 0):

As I have been facing this issue for quite some time, finally decided to fix it today and decided to share the solution that works perfectly for me.
We are developing a React app as a containerized service using Docker and as a development environment we are using VS Code. Both the remote Linux host folder of the app and its counterpart inside the container are mounted, so when I attach VS Code to the running container and change the code either inside the container or directly on the host machine the changes are automatically applied and the page in the browser reloaded as well.

But I find having to attach VS Code and open the container every time when I need to work on the app somehow annoying, and that's why I explored how I could do it without opening the container but still being able to see my changes automatically and fast applied into the browser.

Seems the solution was pretty simple and it is published on the following page:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

The key flags that should be used here are:

```
WDS_SOCKET_HOST // The dev host machine's IP address where the app resides
```

and

```
WDS_SOCKET_PORT // The dev host machine's port bound as an external port to the Docker's container port where the app is running
```

The bash command that can be used in the docker-compose file should look like this:

```
WDS_SOCKET_HOST=${SERVER_HOST_ADDRESS} WDS_SOCKET_PORT=${WEB_APP_EXTERNAL_PORT} npm start --watch
```

Or the full docker-compose service code:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web-app:
    tty: true
    image: <docker-image-name>
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: <DockerfileName>
    ports:
      - ${WEB_APP_EXTERNAL_PORT}:3000
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_MOUNT_APP_SCRIPTS}:/opt/project/web_app
      - /opt/project/web_app/node_modules
    environment:
      - WEB_APP_API_HOST=${WEB_APP_API_HOST}
    command: 
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        cd /opt/project/web_app;
        WDS_SOCKET_HOST=${SERVER_HOST_ADDRESS} WDS_SOCKET_PORT=${WEB_APP_EXTERNAL_PORT} npm start --watch
```

Hope this would be of help to those who are facing the same challenge! :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to expose the port 3000 from the frontend app in the docker-compose.yml.

I saw in the network tab of the browser that it was trying to connect to a websocket in port 3000.

Im also running this app behind a nginx reverse proxy. But what worked for me is to expose the port. Once this done, hot reload worked again!

```
frontend:
build:
    context: ./frontend
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
container_name: frontend-react
hostname: frontend-react
ports:
    - 3000:3000 
restart: always
environment:
  - WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1 
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true 
volumes:
    - ./frontend:/app
depends_on:
    - backend
    - mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Windows often uses WSL and there are some issues relating to how parts of the filesystem monitor and report changes.

I found a solution to the problem and I've written an article on how to fix it here:
https://dev.to/simplifycomplexity/solving-hot-reload-issues-in-vs-code-dev-containers-on-windows-with-wsl2-16d5

It might be caused by the way WSL2 monitors mounted drives for changes. There's an issue where it will not do this from within a mounted drive (I don't mean a docker volume). So my article describes the steps needed to fix the issue.

I hope my work helps anyone else facing the problem.