# Docker: how to enable hot-reload to react app (mern)

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, hot-reload

I have a question, it is possible to automatically refresh when the code in react has changed?
This is dockerfile of react app:

```
FROM node:18.2.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

And this is the docker-compose i use:

```
  client:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    image: myapp-client
    container_name: myapp-react-client
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network
```

This code not work, some advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hot reload doesn't work in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297042/react-hot-reload-doesnt-work-in-docker-container)

Comment: @helloitsjoe no, doesn't work

Comment: for local development, its better to use node locally. node_modules and package.json provide enough encapsulation and repeatability. Using docker is overhead for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to use build files to render website.

docker-compose.yml: (using volume from react app build folder to update build folder inside container)

```
react:
    container_name: react
    image: react
    build: react
    environment:
      REACT_APP_SERVER: "http://localhost/server"
    expose:
      - 3000
    volumes:
      - ./react/build/:/usr/src/app/build/
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Please also make sure you run command:

```
docker compose up --build
```

instead of "up" only. Maybe this last part (with docker command) is what makes problem the most.

Each time you update the code, you will have to build the application (npm run build) and latest changes will reflect inside the container as well.

Comment: See this repo as working example: https://github.com/munirmuratovic/react-dotnet-nginx-dockerized (uses .net for backend, but everything else all the same)