# Docker hot reload with NextJS

Tags: javascript, docker, next.js

I am having troubles setting up hot reload with Docker and NextJS, basically when I try to change and save a file it doesn't reload the server.

The following is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mainapp:
    build: ./mainapp
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mainapp:/mainapp
  subapp:
    build: ./apps/subapp
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./apps/subapp:/subapp
  mainappdb:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=...
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - mainappdb:/var/lib/postgres/mainappdb
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
volumes:
  mainappdb:
    driver: local
```

This is the Dockerfile of the mainapp:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is the Dockerfile of the subapp:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is the next.config.js of the mainapp:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpackDevMiddleware: config => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    }
    return config
  },
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: false,
  images: {
    domains: [...],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is the next.config.js of the subapp:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: '/subapp',
  webpack: (config, context) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300
    }
    return config
  },
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

The directory tree looks like this:

```
/myapplication/apps/subapp
    |
    |--> Dockerfile
    |
    |--> (all the nextjs code)
/myapplication/mainapp
    |
    |--> Dockerfile
    |
    |--> (all the nextjs code)
/myapplication/nginx
    |
    |--> Dockerfile
    |
    |--> default.conf
/myapplication/docker-compose.yml
```

Maybe the problem is because I am using the WORKDIR instruction in the Dockerfile?

Comment: This is a common issue, where you take a Dockerfile that's designed to package an app and try to get it to do hot reload. The Dockerfile is just not designed to do that, and you should use a different Dockerfile. One key question that illustrates this is "if your source code is on the host machine and reloaded from there, why do you then copy it into the image in the Dockerfile?"

Comment: @HansKilian thanks for the response, do you have any suggestions on what type of Dockerfile I should use?

Comment: I wrote the accepted answer on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297042/react-hot-reload-doesnt-work-in-docker-container

Comment: Can you use Node directly, without Docker?  Since you're working directly on the host system in that case, you're not introducing a filesystem isolation layer that you're then trying to work around.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using Docker to deploy my application just to make scalability easier in the future, avoiding to reconfigure anything for each new server, I just download the image and install it in the machine.

Comment: You can definitely develop locally and use Docker for deployment.  There's no requirement that your development setup must exactly match your production environment.

Comment: https://medium.com/@elifront/best-next-js-docker-compose-hot-reload-production-ready-docker-setup-28a9125ba1dc

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in your next.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, _) => ({
    ...config,
    watchOptions: {
      ...config.watchOptions,
      poll: 800,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    },
  }),
}
```

That worked for me.